# Fonts generated with Font Squirrel do not display in IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, font-face

I have used the Fontsquirrel [@fontface Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to create the  CSS for the three fonts I am using. The fonts are displaying properly in every browser including other versions of IE -- but IE 9 is not displaying the fonts.

**Here is the CSS:**

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: "OswaldBold";
    src: url("../fonts/oswald-bold-webfont.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/oswald-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("../fonts/oswald-bold-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../fonts/oswald-bold-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("../fonts/oswald-bold-webfont.svg#OswaldBold") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "OswaldRegular";
    src: url("../fonts/oswald-regular-webfont.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/oswald-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("../fonts/oswald-regular-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../fonts/oswald-regular-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("../fonts/oswald-regular-webfont.svg#OswaldRegular") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "OswaldLight";
    src: url("../fonts/oswald-light-webfont.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/oswald-light-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("../fonts/oswald-light-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../fonts/oswald-light-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("../fonts/oswald-light-webfont.svg#OswaldLight") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

**...and here are the errors I am getting in the IE developer console:**

> CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error.
> oswald-light-webfont.eot?#iefix
>
> CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error.
> oswald-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix
>
> CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error.
> oswald-light-webfont.woff
>
> CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error.
> oswald-bold-webfont.woff
>
> CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable.
> oswald-light-webfont.ttf
>
> CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable.
> oswald-bold-webfont.ttf

I haven't had any luck with the searches I've done, any insight would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have a link to the site / page with the font not working?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I fixed the problem by generating the font files again using the  [Font Squirrel generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).

I selected the 'expert' control option and changed from 'EOT Compressed' to 'EOT Lite'

The fonts now work in every browser.

[image]

Comment: **+1** The generated TTF and WOF2 output files wouldn't work but the generated WOFF file did in **all** the browsers. Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. I received the following error

```
CSS3114: @font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable. File: IcoMoon.ttf
```

My CSS syntax was:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'IcoMoon';
    src: url('font/IcoMoon.eot');
    src: url('font/IcoMoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
    src: url('font/IcoMoon.woff') format('woff');
    src: url('font/IcoMoon.svg#IcoMoon') format('svg');
    src: url('font/IcoMoon.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I solved it by rearranging it like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'IcoMoon';
    src: url('font/IcoMoon.eot');
    src: url('font/IcoMoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('font/IcoMoon.woff') format('woff'),
        url('font/IcoMoon.svg#IcoMoon') format('svg'),
        url('font/IcoMoon.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To fix CSS114 use this little app: [Truetype embedding-enabler](http://carnage-melon.tom7.org/embed/)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem where the icons would not show up in any version of IE with Font Awesome. I simply changed the format for IE from "eot" to "embedded-opentype" and that corrected the issue.

EXAMPLE:
OLD - src: url('./font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot')
NEW - src: url('./font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype')